# Redirecting MATLAB's disp to a text string

Tags: matlab

Say that, on a MATLAB interactive session, I call a function from a third party library `output = long_execution(input)`. This function prints information via [`disp`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2010a/techdoc/ref/disp.html) statements to the command window. I would like to capture the output of such [`disp`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2010a/techdoc/ref/disp.html) statements on a text string that I can manipulate in MATLAB.

Is there a (hopefully easy) way of redirecting the output of [`disp`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2010a/techdoc/ref/disp.html) to a text string? If so, how would you do it? (maybe via the overlading of [`disp`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2010a/techdoc/ref/disp.html)?)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Suppressing a function's command window output in Matlab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029636/suppressing-a-functions-command-window-output-in-matlab)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use evalc function to capture disp outputs. For example,

```
    [T, output] = evalc('long_execution(input)');
```

Anything that would normally go to command window is captured into the output T.

Answer (score 4):

If everything is going into stdout, you can use the [`diary`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/diary.html) function to capture that and write it to file, then after execution you can use any number of matlab file reading utilities to parse through it. You might also find the function [`tempdir`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/tempdir.html) and [`tempname`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/tempname.html) useful in this context.