# Writing display-formatted strings to disk in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, number-formatting

Say I want to print to disk the output of the command `magic(20)` using the automatic formatting capabilities in MATLAB (i.e. those of `display` and `disp`)

I would like to do this programatically from MATLAB. So my take so far has been:

First I configure my formatting options.

```
format bank
format compact
```

Then I open a file in text mode and write permission:

```
fID = fopen('output_file.txt', 'wt');
```

And then, I try to save the output of specific statements to disk:

#### 1) With `num2str`

```
string = num2str(magic(20));
fwritef(fID, '%s', string);
```

#### 2) With `eval` (based on the most-voted answer on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6654975/redirecting-matlabs-disp-to-a-text-string))

```
string = eval('magic(20)');
fwritef(fID, '%s', string);
```

Is there any way to use `display` or `disp` in combination with `fprintf` (or a similar text-file-writing API) to write disp/display-formatted strings to disk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're on linux or OS X you could run your script from the command line and redirect stdout to a file.  You may want to check on the syntax, but it's something like

```
matlab -r my_function > out.txt
```

I think there's a way to do it from a DOSish prompt as well, though I don't know the redirect syntax there.

**Update: Non-redirecting version**

Does something like this work?

```
format bank
format compact

s1 = evalc('magic(4)');
s2 = evalc('disp(magic(4))');

f = fopen('test.txt', 'w');
fprintf(f, '%s', s1);
fprintf(f, '\n======================================\n\n');
fprintf(f, '%s', s2);
fclose(f)
```

If I run this and then do `!cat test.txt`, I get

```
ans =
     16.00          2.00          3.00         13.00
      5.00         11.00         10.00          8.00
      9.00          7.00          6.00         12.00
      4.00         14.00         15.00          1.00

======================================

     16.00          2.00          3.00         13.00
      5.00         11.00         10.00          8.00
      9.00          7.00          6.00         12.00
      4.00         14.00         15.00          1.00
```

Comment: Thanks @dantswain, but I am interested in writing to disk only specific strings, not the full `stdout` of my program/function/script.

Comment: Fair enough.  This is just the quick solution that came to mind.  Looking at the above, it's not clear *what* is not working about what you're doing.  Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want `evalc`. It will capture the command window output of an `eval` to a string.

```
x = magic(20);
str = evalc('disp(x)');
fprintf(fid, 'My matrix is:\n%s', str);
```