# Get stdout error message from an external library loaded in Matlab

Tags: matlab, dll, error-handling, stdout, stderr

In Matlab, I successfully managed to load [this external library](https://logiciels.cnes.fr/en/content/propa) using

```
[notfound,warnings] = loadlibrary('propa64','propa');
```

I then call the library functions thanks to `calllib`; for example:

```
rainHeight = calllib('propa64','rain_height',lat,lon);
```

If I pass to the `rain_height` function a wrong latitude value (`lat = 92`, for example), it returns with an error message like:

```
Latitude value out of valid range [-90�;90�].
```

and a `NaN` value is assigned to `rainHeight`.
While *in the Matlab code* I can check if `rainHeight` value is a `NaN`, I'd like also to return the error given by `rain_height`, which is most probably written to stdout or stderr.

Is there a way to pass the error issued by the dll to a Matlab variable by means of `calllib` or any other function?

Comment: Have you tried anything listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6654975/52738)?

Comment: thanks! evalc is not suitable because, according to its definition, it does not record error messages. checking the others

Comment: `diary` looked promising, but unfortunately does not record stdout

Comment: How is the error being displayed? Is it just printed to stdout, or does it show up in red as an actual error?

Comment: I'd say the first one. If i run matlab from terminal, the error shows up in the cli (stdout), and not in the matlab window

Comment: If the output is showing up in the command window, I would expect `evalc` to work. Otherwise, [this post](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/102200-how-can-i-capture-stdout-of-a-generic-shared-library-method-called-from-matlab) suggests that there is no way to capture stdout or stderr other than to display it in a new console window.