# How to "silence" a Matlab function?

Tags: matlab

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Suppressing a function’s command window output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029636/suppressing-a-functions-command-window-output)
>   [Suppress Output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9518146/suppress-output)

Is there a way to "silence" the output of a Matlab function? In other words, if a function generates some displayed text in the command window, is there a way to run it in a quiet mode, where the output is suppressed?

In my case, I am using a third-party function iteratively that displays a lot of text, and I want to find a way to suppress that text without modifying the function itself. I'm thinking there must be some kind of wrapper function like `quiet(thirdpartyFunction)` that gives this kind of behavior. Or is this wishful thinking?

Comment: Are you asking about returned values, or about values emitted during the execution of the function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can probably use `evalc` and discard the return value.

Comment: This did the trick for me, thanks! Note to others: It is possible to also capture the function's normal output variables using evalc. See the second syntax option for how to do this, i.e.[T, X, Y, Z, ...] = evalc(S).