# It there a way to suppress results display of external function in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I'm using some third-party package on MATLAB for data analysis. It was compiled using C#, but by default it displayed the results. I want to suppress this display, but should modify the C codes to achieve this. As I'm not familiar with C# and thus it troubles me to re-compile the modified codes, I wonder whether there is a general way to suppress the display in MATLAB as it has provided a way for each built-in function.

**Edit:**
@bushmills is correct. The function `evalc` suggested in this [*thread*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13606395/how-to-silence-a-matlab-function) works. But it can significantly slow down the computation. Is there a better way, for example, declare `warning('off',msgid)` at the beginning, to suppress display in current function?

Thanks.

Comment: You can't use [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17302847/2338750)? There are input variables when calling `evalc`.

Comment: why not? it seems, that `evalc` is exactly what you are looking for. what's wrong with your complex matrix?

Comment: As far as know there is no way to turn of the console output. Programs are intended to follow what have been written in code. Removing this is about the only way I think. I am not sure what you have done but AFAIK it is not possible to compile C# code in MATLAB (https://se.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/33579-is-it-possible-to-compile-c-code-in-matlab). This makes it complicated to advice you how to remove the printout as well. For c/c++ you will probably have some call to `mexPrintf()` though.

Comment: warning('off',...) will only remove warning messages not normal command line  outputs.