# Supressing console (disp) output for compiled MATLAB > Java program (using MATLAB Compiler)

Tags: java, matlab, console, matlab-deployment

**Edit 2** After recieving a response from Mathworks support I've answered the question myself. In brief, there is an options class `MWComponentOptions` that is passed to the exported class when instantiated. This can, among other things, specify unique print streams for error output and regular output (i.e. from `disp()`-liked functions). Thanks for all the responses none the less :)

====================================================================

Just a quick question - is there any way to prevent MATLAB code from outputting to the Java console with `disp` (and similar) functions once compiled? What is useful debugging information in MATLAB quickly becomes annoying extra text in the Java logs.

The compilation tool I'm using is MATLAB Compiler (which I think is not the same as MATLAB Builder JA, but I might be wrong). I can't find any good documentation on the `mcc` command so am not sure if there are any options for this.

Of course if this is impossible and a direct consequence of the compiler converting all MATLAB code to its Java equivalent then that's completely understandable.

Thanks in advance

**Edit** This will also be useful to handle error reporting on the Java side alone - currently all MATLAB errors are sent to the console regardless of whether they are caught or not.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin could you give an example? I'm not sure how evaluating a C/C++ function in the MATLAB code will make a difference when it's compiled to Java, thought I'd like to look into it

Comment: Sorry I meant to refer to `evalc` (not `ceval`), I got it from this topic which is a possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9518146/suppress-output

Comment: Thanks, that article is quite useful and I'll probably use it to suppress the `disp` output. It doesn't solve the issue with suppressing error output however. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I heard back from a request to Mathworks support, and they provided the following solution:

When creating whatever class has been exported, you can specify an `MWComponentOptions` object. This is poorly documented in R2012b, but for what I wanted the following example would work:

```
MWComponentOptions options = new MWComponentOptions();
PrintStream o = new PrintStream(new File("MATLAB log.log"));

options.setPrintStream(o); // send all standard dips() output to a log file
// the following ignores all error output (this will be caught by Java exception handling anyway)
options.setErrorStream((java.io.PrintStream)null);

// instantiate and use the exported class
myClass obj = new myClass(options);
obj.myMatlabFunction();
// etc...
```

**Update**

In case anyone does want to suppress all output, casing `null` to `java.io.PrintStream` ended up causing a `NullPointerException` in deployment. A better way to suppress all output is use to create a dummy print stream, something like:

```
PrintStream dummy = new PrintStream(new OutputStream() {
    public void close() {}
    public void flush() {}
    public void write(byte[] b) {}
    public void write(byte[] b, int off, int len) {}
    public void write(int b) {}
} );
```

Then use

```
options.setErrorStream(dummy);
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Much nicer than my hack solution, +1

Answer (score 2):

The `isdeployed` function returns true if run in a deployed application (with e.g. MATLAB Compiler or Builder JA) and false when running in live MATLAB.

You can surround your `disp` statements with an `if isdeployed` block.

Comment: useful, but still doesn't solve the problem of error output. thanks :)

Comment: For error output, you could wrap your entire application in a big `try..catch` block. Then if the application is deployed, do nothing, otherwise rethrow the error.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible hack if you have a stand-alone application and don't want to bother with classes at all:

Use evalc and deploy your func name during compile:

```
function my_wrap()
    evalc('my_orig_func(''input_var'')');
end
```

And compile like

```
mcc -m my_wrap my_orig_func <...>
```

Well, it is obviously yet another hack.