# Suppress function output

Tags: matlab

I have a short function which uses `textscan` to read data into a variable.

My problem is that I always get this:

```
>>function('function.txt')

    ans = 

        {10x1 cell}    {10x1 cell}    {10x1 cell}    [10x1 double]
```

Is there any way to suppress this, apart from adding a semi colon to the end of the line I use to call the function? I'd like to be able to suppress it without adding the semi colon. I don't want to display anything at all when running this function, I just want to load my file.

Comment: Oops, mis-read the question. Am deleting my answer.

Comment: Have re-read the question properly now :-) What you want can be done using `evalc` (I think). See [suppress-output](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9518146/suppress-output) and [suppressing-a-functions-command-window-output](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029636/suppressing-a-functions-command-window-output) for near duplicates of this question (I'm flagging this as a possible duplicate).

Answer (score 5):

You can suppress the output by remove output arguments (or return values) of the function.
OR
Try use `Variable Number of Outputs`, see [Support Variable Number of Outputs](http://www.mathworks.cn/cn/help/matlab/matlab_prog/support-variable-number-of-outputs.html)

```
function varargout = foo
    nOutputs = nargout;
    varargout = cell(1,nOutputs);
    for k = 1:nOutputs;
        varargout{k} = k;
    end
end
```

You type `>>foo` and get nothing.
You type `>>a=foo` and get `>>a=1`.
You type `>>[a,b]=foo` and get `>>a=1 >>b=2`.

You can thus suppress output by NOT providing any output arguments.

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way to avoid having output printed out is to not assign the first output argument if no output argument was requested:

```
function [aOut,b,c] = doSomething

%# create a,b,c normally
a = 1;
b = 4;
c = 3;

%# only assign aOut if any output is requested
if nargout > 0
   aOut = a;
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the `diary` functionality. It redirects all input and output from the command prompt to a file of your choice. If you only turn it on during a specific function, no input should be captured.
I admit it is a bit of a clumsy solution as the diary on/off state is global to matlab, but it might be ok in your case.

Read more about it here: 
[Diary matlab help](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/diary.html)