# Matlab: stop terminal message in call to ga (genetic algorithm function)

Tags: matlab, genetic-algorithm

In **matalb** I am implementing genetic algorithm using `ga`. In a typical call to `ga` like `x = ga(nvars,@fitnessfunc)` when returns gives message on *terminal* specifying the reason for the termination of the genetic algorithm. A typical message is:

*Optimization terminated: average change in the fitness value less than options.TolFun.*

I want to turn off this message. I read the documentation but found nothing.

Any ideas?

Comment: You have written matalb instead of matlab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the answer given in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9518146/suppress-output).

Use the [evalc](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/evalc.html) and then you wont display the text plus you can actually read it and use it for your own purposes (like knowing why did it stop etc)

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer [here](http://www.mathworks.in/help/gads/gaoptimset.html) minutes after posting the question. To stop the display we have to set `display` parameter of `options structure` to `'off'`. The proper code is below:

```
problem.solver = 'ga';
problem.options = gaoptimset('display','off','param2','value2'...);
problem.fitnessfnc = @fitness;
problem.nvars = nvars;
output = ga(problem);
```