# Suppress all warnings in MATLAB on server

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, sbatch

I am running a batched analysis on a server (using SBATCH slurm) using `glmfit()` 10<sup>6</sup> times and it keeps outputting warning files that **don't appear when I run on local**. I get multiple types of warning types

```
Warning: Iteration limit reached

Warning: The estimated coefficients perfectly separate failures from successes

...
```

All warnings are generated in `glmfit()` with `warning(message(...))`

As a result I can't look at my debug outputs. I include `warning('off','all')` at the top of every script in the analysis but I am still getting multiple warning outputs to an output file I write to with

```
#SBATCH -o <analysis_name>-%j.out
#SBATCH -e <analysis_name>-%j.out
```

I've tried dropping the `-e` line but still received the error logs (because they were MATLAB, not system errors).

Comment: Would [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9518146/suppress-output) be helpful?

Comment: Since I'm calling `glmfit(<sliced variables>,..)` in parallel, I cannot use `evalc()` because it violates transparency in that context

Comment: Do you have the same Matlab version on local and on the cluster?

Comment: Yep, R2016b on both

Answer (score 0):

Encountered this issue now exactly as described and this is what solved it.
With this change the warning shows once. If you are running a parallel loop, then it will show once for every worker.

At the head of the iteration do:

```
lastwarn('', '');
```

Then, after, where the warning happens, do:

```
[warnMsg, warnId] = lastwarn();
if (~isempty(warnId))
    warning('off', warnId);
end
```