# Matlab libsvm svmpredict accuracy verbose

Tags: matlab, libsvm, verbose

I have a question of an annoying fact. I'm using libsvm with matlab and I'am able to predict using:

```
predicted_label = svmpredict(Ylabel, Xlabel, model);
```

but it happen that every time I make a predictions appears this:

```
Accuracy = X% (y/n) (classification)
```

Which I find annoying because I am repeating this procedure a lot of times and also makes it slow because its displaying in screen.

I think what I want is to avoid that svmpredict being verbose.

Can anyone help me with this? Thanks in advance.

-Jessica

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using matlab, just find the line of code that is displaying this information (usually using **'disp'**, **'sprintf'**, or **'fprintf'**) and comment it out using the commenting operator **%**.

example:

```
disp(['Accuracy= ' num2str(x)]);
```

change it to:

```
% disp(['Accuracy= ' num2str(x)]);
```

If you are using the main libsvm library then you need to modify it before making.
1- Open the file **'svmpredict.c'**

2- find this line of code:

```
info("Accuracy = %g%% (%d/%d) (classification)\n",
(double)correct/total*100,correct,total);
```

3- just comment it out using **//** operator

4- save and close the file

5- make the project

Comment: In addition to these suggestions, you may take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029636/suppressing-a-functions-command-window-output

Answer (score 7):

I found a much better approach than editing the source code of the c library was to use matlabs [evalc](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/evalc.html) which places any output to the first output argument.

```
[~ predicted_label] = evalc('svmpredict(Ylabel, Xlabel, model)');
```

Because the string to be evaluated is fixed should be no performance decrease.

Comment: I found this the easiest and most straight-forward solution

Comment: Unfortunately this seems to be the only way to achieve this (without recompiling the source).

Answer (score 6):

```
svmpredict(Ylabel, Xlabel, model, '-q');
```

From the manual:

```
Usage: [predicted_label, accuracy, decision_values/prob_estimates] = svmpredict(testing_label_vector, testing_instance_matrix, model, 'libsvm_options')
       [predicted_label] = svmpredict(testing_label_vector, testing_instance_matrix, model, 'libsvm_options')
Parameters:
  model: SVM model structure from svmtrain.
  libsvm_options:
    -b probability_estimates: whether to predict probability estimates, 0 or 1 (default 0); one-class SVM not supported yet
    -q : quiet mode (no outputs)
```

Comment: Unfortunately quiet mode still has some outputs. Not no outputs. If you are doing grid based hyper-parameter searches your command line can still get flooded.

Comment: Not really an answer to the question because this still outputs the `Accuracy = ...` message that the OP was trying to hide.