# Matlab: suppressing standard output of fmincon?

Tags: matlab, stdout, verbosity

I want to suppress the standard output of the [fmincon](http://www.mathworks.se/help/optim/ug/fmincon.html) like the below

```
Optimization completed because the objective function is non-decreasing in 
feasible directions, to within the default value of the function tolerance,
and constraints are satisfied to within the default value of the constraint tolerance.

<stopping criteria details>

Active inequalities (to within options.TolCon = 1e-06):
  lower      upper     ineqlin   ineqnonlin
    1          1                      
    2          2                      
    3          3                      
    4          4                      
    5          5                      
    6          6                      
    7          7
```

which is fired each time I use fmincon to find the minimum of a multivariate function.

```
    x0=lb; %guess
    A=[];
    b=[];
    Aeq=[];
    beq=[];

    global mlf1;
    mlf1=mlf;
    [x,fval]=fmincon(@HenriMLF.mlfEvalAtPoint,x0,A,b,Aeq,beq,lb,ub);
```

So **how to suppress the stdout of the fmincon?**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Suppressing a function's command window output](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029636/suppressing-a-functions-command-window-output)

Comment: Not a duplicate, I just reviewed it, a competely different issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before calling fmincon() you need to set various options which control how the function is applied.

In your case you will want to set 'Display' to 'off' like:

```
options = optimoptions('Display', 'off');
```

So in your case something like this should work:

```
[x,fval]=fmincon(@HenriMLF.mlfEvalAtPoint,x0,A,b,Aeq,beq,lb,ub,options);
```

More [documentation is here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fmincon.html).

Comment: Nice one +1! I tried to use the `[T,x,y,...]=evalc(fmincon(...))` as offered by the other reply but I did not get it working like that.