# Suppress itermsg in matlab

Tags: matlab

I am using this pcg function in matlab. However it outputs the iteration message like this

```
pcg converged at iteration 5 to a solution with relative residual 9.3e-07.
```

I want to suppress this message. I have found that I can suppress this message with the flag option in the output. So if I do something like this

```
[x flag] = pcg(...)
```

it suppresses the output. However, I cannot do that in my case. Is there any other way. When I went through the code of pig, I could see that it prints the message using itermsg function. Is there any way to suppress this function?

Comment: So you can't use `[x,~]=...` either? Are you using this in an anonymous function? Is that why you can't have more than one output? How about creating a helper function to capture the output? And you could always edit the code for `pcg` (or `private/itermsg`) or create your version. There doesn't seem to be any `options` structure as is common with many optimization functions.

Comment: Some options [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029636/suppressing-a-functions-command-window-output), but I don't think the `evalc` one will work for you because of the order of it's output arguments.

Comment: can't you just in the code comment the message line? using %

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a helper function,

```
function [x,flag,relres,iter,resvec] = pcg_quiet(varargin)
[x,flag,relres,iter,resvec] = pcg(varargin{:});
```

The function pcg_quiet will act identitcal to pcg, except without the text. For example,

```
>>> x = pcg_quiet(A,b);
```