# How can I prevent external function from writing to console?

Tags: matlab

I have a MatLab function in which I have a for-loop that make a call in every iteration to an external function from a library.

Unfortunately this function produces a hundred lines of console output on every call and my for-loop (parfor to be precise) has a number of iterations in the order of 10k-100k!

So I am addressing basically 2 problems:

- Output console is extremely confusing and hardly readable
- A consistent (or near so) slow down in code execution

The first problem is the most annoying at the moment but I would like to solve both.

I am wondering if there is a way to prevent a function to produce text output.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Suppressing a function's command window output](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029636/suppressing-a-functions-command-window-output)

Comment: In the end I used evalc as suggested in the other question and in this one by Daniel.

The only problem was about evalc that cannot be used in parfor, so I wrapped my evalc in another function and all just worked fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two possibilities:

1. You can create a `private` folder next to the function and place an empty function `fprintf` (or whatever is used to print) inside. This way you are overwriting the build-in function with a new one simply doing nothing.
2. use `evalc` to run the function.