# Not displaying any comments on command window

Tags: matlab

I am using a combination of matlab codes with some C++ libraries as .mex files. Those .mex files display some progress reports on my command window which I do not want to see them.

Is these any way to cancel those outputs on my command window?

Comment: This answer applies to any function, including C++ code. http://stackoverflow.com/a/3029883/2732801

Comment: evalc does not for disp in matlab! and it also does not work for the .mex file!!

Comment: I should put my function in '...' as a string to evalc!

Comment: It stops the "disp" output, but I still cannot stop the output of .exe files! any solutions?

Comment: what about `evalc('!ping 127.0.0.1')` or similar? Currently not using windows so I can't try with exe files.

Comment: what is that? do you have a better example/test?

Comment: That is an example calling the `ping.exe` which some parameters to generate output. What "better" example do you want?

Comment: It works for me, windows 7, matlab 2014b. I suppose you need to do the call as `evalc('!ping 127.0.0.1');` to not write out anything. Note the `;`. FYI, the program `ping.exe` performs a so called `Ping test`. This is a standardized test to check the connection to another device in an IP network. The IP 127.0.0.1 refers to local device (your own computer).

Comment: I tired that and still see some outputs on my command window !

Comment: @patrik: Thx for the correction, forgetting the `;` especially in this case was very stupid. @Sam what OS / Matlab version do you use? With `evalc('!ping 127.0.0.1');` I don't see any output. Did you try it with `ping` or with your application?

Comment: I had put ; and it did work and forgot to update it here.